# splitting a div content into pages like pdf

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I am creating a resume application and I want to show the preview(html) of the resume into multiple divs or insert an horizontal row if the resume fields or content overflows the div height so that it looks separated like pdf pages(one below another).  Currently it is being shown in a single div. The fields and height of the resume is dynamic. The max height of each div will be 900px.
Any ideas?

Here is the code-

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="line-height: 1.4;">  
            <div class="editSection"> <span class="editicon" ng-click="editSection(2)"><img src="images/editIcon.jpg" alt="edit" /></span><span style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; display: block;">{{resume.basicDetails.firstName+" "+resume.basicDetails.lastName}}</span></div>
            <div class="editSection"> <span class="editicon" ng-click="editSection(2)"><img src="images/editIcon.jpg" alt="edit" /></span><span style="display: block; text-align: center; font-size:14px; ">Phone: {{resume.basicDetails.phone | tel}} | Email: {{resume.basicDetails.email}} |
Address: {{resume.basicDetails.address}}, {{resume.basicDetails.city}}, {{resume.basicDetails.state}} {{resume.basicDetails.country != 'United States' ? resume.basicDetails.country : ''}}</span></div><br>
            <div ng-if="resume.summary">
                <div style="text-align: center;" class="strike"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;">PROFESSIONAL SUMMARY</span></div><br>
                <div class="editSection"> <span class="editicon" ng-click="editSection(3)"><img src="images/editIcon.jpg" alt="edit" /></span>
                <div style="text-align:justify;text-justify: inter-word;-moz-text-align-last: justify;text-align-last: justify;">{{resume.summary}}</div></div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="strike" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;">EDUCATION</span></div>
<br><div class="editSection" ng-repeat="education in resume.educationDetails track by $index"> <span class="editicon" ng-click="editSection(4)"><img src="images/editIcon.jpg" alt="edit" /></span>
 <div class="clearfix"><span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px; float: left;">{{education.institute}}</span><span style="float: right;">{{education.state}}{{education.country != 'United States' ? ', '+education.country : ''}}</span></div>
     <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      <div class="clearfix"><span style="display: block;float: left;">{{education.course}}</span><span style="float: right;">{{education.startDate | date:'MMM yyyy'}}—{{education.enrolled ? 'Present' : education.endDate | date:'MMM yyyy'}}</span></div><br>
     </div><br>
            <div style="text-align: center;clear:both;" class="strike"><span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;">EXPERIENCE</span></div><br>
            <div class="editSection" ng-repeat="experience in resume.experienceDetails track by $index"> <span class="editicon" ng-click="editSection(3)"><img src="images/editIcon.jpg" alt="edit" /></span>
                          <div><span style="font-weight: bold; display: block; font-size: 16px; float: left;">{{experience.name}}</span><span style="float: right; font-style: italic;">{{experience.startDate | date:'MMM yyyy'}}—{{experience.employed ? 'Present' : experience.endDate | date:'MMM yyyy'}}</span></div>
     <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      <div><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; float: left; font-style: italic;">{{experience.position}}</span><span style="float: right;">{{experience.state}}, {{experience.city}}{{experience.country != 'United States' ? ', '+experience.country : ''}}</span></div>
     <div style="clear: both;"></div>            <br>
     <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="res in experience.responsibilities track by $index">{{res}}</li> 
        </ul>
    </div></div><br>
    <div ng-if="resume.skills && resume.skills[0].skill">
<div style="text-align: center;" class="strike"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;">ASSETS</span></div><br><div class="editSection"> <span class="editicon" ng-click="editSection(3)"><img src="images/editIcon.jpg" alt="edit" /></span>
             <ul style="list-style:none;padding-left:0;">
     <li ng-repeat="skill in resume.skills track by $index">            <span style="font-size: 16px;font-weight:bold">{{skill.skill}}</span> : {{skill.description}} </li>
</ul>
             </div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any code for the current status of your project?

Comment: added the code now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following technique to spit your content across different page when printing it.

```js
window.print();
```

```css
    
    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0;
    }
    @media print {
        html, body {
            width: 210mm;
            height: 297mm;        
        }
        .page {
            margin: 0;
            border: initial;
            border-radius: initial;
            width: initial;
            min-height: initial;
            box-shadow: initial;
            background: initial;
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="book">
    <div class="page">
        Page 1/2 - Your content here
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        Page 2/2 - Your content here
    </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise you can use `page-break-before`

```
<div class="page-break"></div>

@media all {
.page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
.page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

```js
window.print();
```

```css
@media all {
.page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
.page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

```html
<div>Some content BEFORE the page break</div>
<div class="page-break"></div>
<div>Some content AFTER the page break</div>
<div class="page-break"></div>
<div> ... More content after another page break ... </div>
```

Comment: As I already mentioned I am not looking for a solution for print layout. I need to render it in this way on a html page

Answer (score 0):

We have a CSS property "page-break-after", which you can assign to HTML tags. Have you ever tried that?

Maybe it's a good idea to apply these rules specifically to print, like this:

```
@media print {
    footer { page-break-after: always; }
}
```

More info: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/

Comment: I tried this but it is not applicable in this case.

Comment: And this css is for printing only